# Which Geodatabase version is holding how manyUNPOSTED outstanding Edits?

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, versioning, arcgis-10.4

I have this generic versioned geodatabase question i.e.Which Geodatabase version is holding how many UNPOSTED outstanding Edits ?, which may be crucial to identify the query performance bottleneck in any versioned enterprise geodatabase having large number of editors. 
I have posted this query multiple times  including Esri support however could not get satisfactory resolution.
Version for ArcSDE10.2.2 to 10.4

Comment: You probably need to review how versioning works. A "version" is only a named state in the state tree, but there could be many orphaned states which don't have any associated version. You'd have to provide a great more detail about your state tree before anyone here could help you.

Comment: We have all versions created from DEFAULT as Parent only.Yes I agree there may be many orphaned states, Is there any way to compare version state with Default state irrespective of orphaned state in between?

Comment: On a database level perhaps... what DB are you using? This kind of poking around in the 'back end' I would **strongly discourage** unless you *really* know what you're doing (or are prepared to rebuild your database from scratch). Have you tried to compress the database to reconcile outstanding edits to DEFAULT (or are all your edits in states other than DEFAULT?).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the Version Differences tool in ArcMap, see http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/data-reviewer/comparing-geodatabase-versions.htm.  This gives you information on the outstanding Adds, Deletes, and Modifies between versions.

Granted, you would need to do this on a version by version basis, but this may give you the answer you are looking for.

You could also use ArcObjects to create a tool that goes through all versions and gets a count of the differences using the *IVersionedWorkspace*, *IVersionedTable*, and *IDifferenceCursor* interfaces.  See [How to identify Unposted/Outstanding (A&D) edits of a version in Enterprise SDE Database using SQL interface?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/136711/how-to-identify-unposted-outstanding-ad-edits-of-a-version-in-enterprise-sde) for more details.